# Getting specific data from Mysql database, based on user login

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

So I have a simple working user log in script that carries forward myusername and mypassword.

What I am trying (and failing) to do is recall a specific piece of information from that users Mysql database to modify the page that they are on.

```
MYSQL DATABASE ('members'): 
id:1
username:cornellmatt
password:encrypted(md5)
email:example@email.com
active: 0/1
**permission:1**
```

The field I need to extract is permission, as it holds the number that will relate the the scene that the user is currently on.
In order to do this I am running Jquery on the page that you arrive at after logging in, that links to connect.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.get("connect.php", function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

I understand that there are all kinds of problems with my JavaScript at the moment, but for now I want to get the server side stuff done so I can focus on the JavaScript fully
The (Current) problem with my Php is that it doesn't seem to be getting anything from the database at all, I know it is connected, it just wont echo the value inside 'permission';

**connect.php:**

```
<?php
include "Session.php"; 

$dbhost = "host";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";
    //Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    // Retrieve data from Query String


//this selects everything for the current user, ready to be used in the script below

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$myusername' LIMIT 1");

//this function will take the above query and create an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

 //with the array created above, I can create variables (left) with the outputted array (right)
$permission = $row['permission'];
  } 


        echo '<u><b>Permision ID:</b></u> - - No:' . $row['permission']  ;
?>
```

If you are wondering what'Session.php' is, it is a script that handles the startup, and is the reason I know I am still logged in. Courtesy of Daryl Gill who helped me in a previous post.

**Session.php**

```
 <?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['Username']))
{
 include "Logout.php"; 
 exit;
// session is not set, so enforce logout
}
?>
```

So my quest is, Why doesn't connect.php echo the value permission, even when I go to the page direct? Please help, I am currently coding this for my student project and have been going in circles for days.

Comment: I've removed the database credentials from your question. If these credentials were valid you may want to delete this question, change your password and re-ask it as they will still appear in the edit history.

Comment: Also change your password on every other service where that password is used.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was in a bit of a state when I put this up, my mind was fried, thanks for editing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$_SESSION['Username']` is not set you have putted `exit;`

And because of that it doesn't prints `permission`

And When you do `Ajax` call may be the `$_SESSION['Username']` is set and it prints `permission`.

Also change

```
echo '<u><b>Permision ID:</b></u> - - No:' . $row['permission']  ;
```

to

```
echo '<u><b>Permision ID:</b></u> - - No:' . $permission;
```

Because outside while loop you can't access $row['permission'].

Comment: Ok I changed it to the php variable now, and I understand why it didn't work, thank you so much for the feedback

Comment: @MattCornell Glad it helped.. Accept the appropriate answer which has helped you..

Answer (score 1):

`$row['permission']` doesn't exist here. You just need `$permission.`

`echo '<u><b>Permision ID:</b></u> - - No:' . $permission;`

Comment: I entered it in that format and now it works, thank you so much

Comment: Mark as answered please :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get any rows by doing this:

> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
>         var_dump($row);
>         $permission = $row['permission'];
>       }

Comment: Thanks, now I can see exactly what's happening